# How to format prices in JS

Tags: javascript, currency-formatting

I'm using currencyFormatter for my prices, and I would like to present my prices with the euro sign after the price and a full stop instead of a comma

Ej. 10.000€ (10 thousand euro).

```
(10000).toLocaleString(xxxx, {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
});
```

Does anyone know which unit I should use in the **xxxx**? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Set it to `undefined` to use browser language. Set to something like `en-US` to overwrite the locale.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest playing around with the locales a bit, or just leave it as undefined to use the user's locale. It appears that 'de-DE' (Germany) appears fairly close to your desired format.

As for the euro sign, you need to have `currency: 'EUR'` for that.

```js
console.log((10000).toLocaleString('de-DE', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'EUR',
  maximumFractionDigits: 0
}));
```

`number#toLocaleString` uses the arguments from [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) which I'd suggest reading through.

In this case, I used `maximumFractionDigits` to remove the values after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

toLocaleString should be "en-US"